# Wait until multiple command line processes complete?

Tags: c#, command-line, process, wait

I have a need to execute many command line scripts. They are currently stored in a `List`. I want to run them all at the same time and proceed with the next step *only* after all of them have completed.

I have tried the approach that I show below, but found it lacking because the last command doesn't necessarily *end* last. In fact, I found that the last command can even be the *first* to complete. So, I believe that I need something like `WaitForExit()`, but which doesn't return until *all* executing processes have completed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < commands.Count; i++)
{
    string strCmdText = commands[i];
    var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
    if (i == (commands.Count - 1))
    {
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
//next course of action once all the above is done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since each call to `Process.Start` starts a new process, you can track them all separately, like so:

```
var processes = new List<Process>();
for (int i = 0; i < commands.Count; i++)
{
    string strCmdText = commands[i];
    processes.Add(System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText));
}

foreach(var process in processes)
{
    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();
}
```

**EDIT**

`Process.Close()` added as in the comments

Comment: I find this solution better than any offered task parallel approach, since it does not unnecessarily use/create further threads

Comment: Is it necessary to call process.Close()? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Probably not strictly necessary, as `Process` inherits a finalizer from `Component`, but it's good practice to dispose early.  It's also easy enough to do in this example (simply call `Close()` after `WaitForExit()` in each loop iteration).

Comment: @Edin exactly. I don't see any reason to pretend your program is doing parallelization when actually it's just external processes that are running at the same time

Answer (score 5):

Use a Task array and wait for all of them to complete.

```
var tasks = new Task[commands.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < commands.Count; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
       string strCmdText = commands[i];
       var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
       process.WaitForExit();
    });
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Or, more LINQ-ishly like this:

```
var tasks = commands.Select(strCmdText => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
    process.WaitForExit();
})).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 1):

At least on Windows, you could use [`WaitHandle.WaitAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitall?view=netframework-4.6.1).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using static System.FormattableString;

public class ProcessWaitHandle : WaitHandle
{
    public ProcessWaitHandle(Process process) =>
        this.SafeWaitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(process.Handle, false);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int processesCount = 42;
        var processes = new Process[processesCount];
        var waitHandles = new WaitHandle[processesCount];
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; processesCount > i; ++i)
            {
                // exit immediately with return code i
                Process process = Process.Start(
                    "cmd.exe",
                    Invariant($"/C \"exit {i}\""));

                processes[i] = process;
                waitHandles[i] = new ProcessWaitHandle(process);
            }

            WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
                    Invariant($"process with Id {p.Id} exited with code {p.ExitCode}"));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                p?.Dispose();
            }

            foreach (WaitHandle h in waitHandles)
            {
                h?.Dispose();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }
}
```

This approach offers the possibility to also use other `WaitAll` overloads, and wait with timeouts, for example.