# Wait for multiple processes to complete

Tags: c#, process, parallel-processing, wait

I want my program to wait for all processes to finish and then delete some temporary files. I already have a block of code that can do this when dealing with one process at a time, but I can't make it work for *multiple* processes.

I'll start by showing the code that works. This code correctly runs a process, waits for it to finish, and then deletes the temporary file:

```
foreach (string script in scriptList)
{
     ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
     myProcess.FileName = accoreconsolePath;
     myProcess.Arguments = "/s \"" + script + "\"";
     myProcess.CreateNoWindow = true;         
     Process myWait = Process.Start(myProcess);
     myWait.WaitForExit();

     File.Delete(script);            
}
```

The above is neatly contained within the `foreach` loop. What I can't get working is a *parallel* version of this where the wait statement is outside of the foreach loop:

```
  Process myWait;
  foreach (string script in scriptList)
  {
     ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
     myProcess.FileName = accoreconsolePath;
     myProcess.Arguments = "/s \"" + script + "\"";
     myProcess.CreateNoWindow = true;
     myWait = Process.Start(myProcess);
  }
  myWait.WaitForExit();                             //error: use of unassigned local variable "myWait"
  //delete file would go here
```

I think I just need to initialize `myWait` before going into the `foreach` loop, but I don't know how to do that. How do I initialize a process without assigning it to anything? Is there some other simple way to do this?

Comment: `List<Process> myWait = new List<Process>();`

Comment: Have a look at this quite similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23741387/594832

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait till multiple command line actions complete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741237/how-to-wait-till-multiple-command-line-actions-complete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store the process handles in a dictionary of script vs process handle, and then later wait for all processes to exit. Below is the code:

```
var processes = new Dictionary<string,Process>();

foreach (string script in scriptList)
{
    ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
     myProcess.FileName = accoreconsolePath;
     myProcess.Arguments = "/s \"" + script + "\"";
     myProcess.CreateNoWindow = true;
     myWait = Process.Start(myProcess);
     processes.Add(script, myWait);
}

foreach(var script in processes.Keys)
{
    Process process = processes[script];

    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();

    File.Delete(script);
}
```

Comment: Iterating a `TKey` over a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and having the first line as an assigment for the `TValue` is the same as iterating a `Pair<TKey, TValue>` over the dictionary and using the `Key` and `Value` properties, except you avoid using the hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this approach was in any of the linked questions from the comments, but here's one that makes use of `List<Task>` and [Task.WaitAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netcore-3.1):

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();            
foreach (string script in scriptList)
{
    string tmpScript = script;
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(delegate {
        ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
        myProcess.FileName = accoreconsolePath;
        myProcess.Arguments = "/s \"" + tmpScript + "\"";
        myProcess.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process.Start(myProcess).WaitForExit();
        File.Delete(tmpScript);
    }));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: WaitForExitAsync() is available starting in CLR 5+ but, if you don't have that available, wrapping the WaitForExit() in an anonymous delegate is a much smaller change than upgrading your runtime. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way for future viewers:

```
var NoOfCores = 4;
Parallel.For(0, scriptList.Count,new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism=NoOfCores }, index =>
{   
    Process proc= new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "filename";
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "optional";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = scriptList[index];   
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    //code here will be executed after finishing each thread
}
//code here will be executed after finishing all the threads
```

or using Parallel.ForEach

```
var NoOfCores = 4;
Parallel.For(0, scriptList,new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism=NoOfCores }, script=>
{   
    Process proc= new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "filename";
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "optional";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = script;   
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    //code here will be executed after finishing each thread
}
//code here will be executed after finishing all the threads
```